# Azure web app uploaded file changes not applied

Tags: file, azure, upload

After changing a file, say myfile.asp, changes to this file are not shown when you invoke the file.

To test, I have deleted the file from the web site. Effectively, when you invoke the file, web says it does not exist. Yet when you re-upload the file, it still does not show your changes.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I kept on trying. UNTIL...
I STOPPED and STARTED the website. problem solved.

Hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: Please activate the checkmark for your answer so that others see it is "the" answer to your problem. And thank you for taking a moment to come back and let everyone know what worked!